# PFTableViewCell init with Coder

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a custom class inheriting from PFTableViewCell. I would like to init the class using a storyboard. I create it using "tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" so I thought I'd need the following initializer.

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //...custom init code...
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work...

[image: Error Message]

Comment: I suggest you read this document from Apple about the initialization chain in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html. Specifically, further down the page about the safety checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an Xcode beta bug. With the release of Xcode6-Beta6 The initialization code was called properly.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the designated initializer for `PFTableViewCell` -- it inherits from `UITableViewCell`, which uses:

```
// Designated initializer.  If the cell can be reused, you must pass in a reuse identifier.  You should use the same reuse identifier for all cells of the same form.  
init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
```

In an inherited designated initializer, you need to set things up in a particular order:

1. Initialize all your own properties
2. Call the superclass initializer
3. Customize any inherited properties and call instance methods

Note that this is different from initialization in Objective-C, where we called `self = [super init]` before doing anything else.

Comment: I had that initializer but it was never called from the class.

var cell : PhotoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier) as PhotoCell!
      
      
if cell == nil {
    cell = PhotoCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
}